# I'm having problems with using Jest, Next.js and Sequelize in a CRUD system project

Tags: next.js, jestjs, sequelize.js

I am new to stack overflow.
I have a problem when I run 'jest' in my next.js project. I'm using Sequelize, Next.js and Jest. I tried to solve it with the help of ChatGPT and no answer worked. This is the response from the terminal:

```
...jest.config.js:1
import nextJest from 'next/jest.js';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at internalCompileFunction (node:internal/vm:73:18)
...
```

This is the GitHub repo of my project: https://github.com/TomiMalamud/dds-tpi

This is the code involved:

'__tests __/jugadores.test.js'

```js
import request from 'supertest';
import server from 'nextjs-http-supertest'; // Librería para testing de Next.js con supertest.

describe('GET /api/jugadores/:id', () => {

  afterAll(() => {
    server.close(); // IMPORTANTE: Cerrar el servidor tipeando "q" en la terminal al terminar los tests
  })

  it('Deberia devolver el jugador con el id 2', async () => {
    const r = await request(server).get('/api/jugadores/2');
    expect(r.statusCode).toEqual(200);
    expect(r.body).toEqual(
      expect.objectContaining({
        Nombre: expect.any(String),
        Apellido: expect.any(String),
        FechaNacimiento: expect.any(String),
      })
    );
  })
})
```

'sequelize-init.js'

```js
import { Sequelize, DataTypes } from 'sequelize';
const sequelize = new Sequelize(`sqlite:./data/futbol.db`);

// Define el modelo de datos Jugadores
const Jugadores = sequelize.define(
  'jugadores',
  {
    IdJugador: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true,
    },
    Nombre: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(30),
      allowNull: false,
      validate: {
        notEmpty: {
          args: true,
          msg: 'Nombre jugador es requerido',
        },
        len: {
          args: [5, 15],
          msg: 'Nombre jugador debe ser tipo caracteres, entre 5 y 15 de longitud',
        },
      },
    },
    Apellido: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(30),
      allowNull: false,
      validate: {
        notEmpty: {
          args: true,
          msg: 'Apellido es requerido',
        },
        len: {
          args: [5, 15],
          msg: 'Apellido debe ser tipo caracteres, entre 5 y 15 de longitud',
        },
      },
    },
    FechaNacimiento: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      validate: {
        notNull: {
          args: true,
          msg: 'Fecha nacimiento es requerida',
        },
      },
    },
  },
  {
    hooks: {
      beforeValidate: (jugador) => {
        if (typeof jugador.Nombre === 'string') {
          jugador.Nombre = jugador.Nombre.toUpperCase().trim();
        }
        if (typeof jugador.Apellido === 'string') {
          jugador.Apellido = jugador.Apellido.toUpperCase().trim();
        }
      },
    },
    timestamps: false,
  }
);
```

I tried to install Jest using the official Next.js docs to do it. But it does not work. I think the problem is Sequelize but I don't really know.

Comment: Replace that import with `const nextJest = require('next/jest');` in your `jest.config.js`.